# Python dot-multiply lists on list of lists, without using numpy

Tags: python, computation, dot-product, mathematical-expressions

I am quite new to python and getting my head around arrays as such, and I am struck on a rather simple problem. I have a list of list, like so:

```
a = [[1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0]]
```

and I would like to multiply elements of each list with each other. Something like:

```
a_dot = [1,0,1,0,1]*[0,0,1,0,1]*[0,0,1,0,1]*[1,1,1,0,1]*[1,0,1,0,0]
=[0,0,1,0,0]
```

Was wondering if I can do the above **without** using numpy/scipy.

Thanks.

Comment: Are your values always 0s and 1s? Because that would allow shortcuts, an element in the result is 0 if there is any 0 in items

Comment: For this case yes, I am dealing only with 0's and 1's - but, I'd like a general solution for this multiplication.

Comment: @AJW: integer or real?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import operator
a_dot = [reduce(operator.mul, col, 1) for col in zip(*a)]
```

But if all your data is 0s and 1s:

```
a_dot = [all(col) for col in zip(*a)]
```

Comment: Never heard of `operator` before. What does this `col, 1`do here?

Comment: Could use some explanation; `zip(*rows)` transposes the matrix, and what do they arguments to `reduce` do.

Comment: `operator.mul` is just a shorthand for `lambda a, b: a * b`. Look at the documentation for reduce

Comment: thanks Eric - your solution is very elegant. Thank you for introducing me to `operator` and `reduce`. Accepted your answer.

Comment: @tobias_k: what is your answer the solution for?

Comment: @AJW Just another way to check whether all the numbers are one, which is equivalent to multiplying them, if they are all just zero or one. If they are not all zero/one, you might want to edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the reduce function? You call it with a function (see it as your operator) and a list and it applies it the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by below code,

```
def multiply(list_a,list_b):
    c = []
    for x,y in zip(list_a,list_b):
        c.append(x*y)
    return c

reduce(lambda list_a,list_b: multiply(list_a,list_b), a)
```

Happy coding!!!!